# Посчитать количество юзеров, которые имеют больше, меньше и равное количество баллов, чем текущий

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица юзеров:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        usr_id       |      name        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         1           |      usr-1       |
|         2           |      usr-2       |
|         3           |      usr-3       |
|         4           |      usr-4       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Есть таблица результатов по какой-либо викторине:

```
|---------------------|-------------|--------|---------|-----------|
|    quiz_res_id      |    user_id  | points | quiz_id | timestamp |
|---------------------|-------------|--------|---------|-----------|
|         1           |      1      |   100  |    1    |   15-00   |
|         2           |      2      |   125  |    1    |   15-01   |
|         3           |      3      |    95  |    1    |   15-02   |
|         4           |      1      |    99  |    1    |   15-11   |
|         5           |      2      |   104  |    2    |   16-00   |
|         6           |      4      |    99  |    1    |   17-00   |
|---------------------|-------------|--------|---------|-----------|
```

Прилетает извне `quiz_id` — ID текущего квиза — и `user_id` — ID текущего юзера.
(Допустим, квиз с ID 1 и юзер с ID 1.

Нужно:

1. По ID юзера и ID викторины найти наиболее свежий (по `timestamp`) результат (`points`) викторины для него.
2. По найденному результату для текущего юзера вывести три числа: число юзеров, у которых `points` больше, меньше и равно числу у текущего юзера (исключая текущего).

Таким образом, результат будет:

```
|---------------------|------------------|-------------|
|      count_less     |    count_equals  |  count_more |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------|
|         1           |         1        |      2      |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------|
```

Comment: И в чём сложности? делайте и показывайте, объясняя, почему так. Если ошибётесь в логике - подскажем. А писать запрос ЗА ВАС никто не будет... да и задача-то в общем простейшая.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `FILTER`:

```sql
WITH latest(quiz_res_id, points) AS (
  SELECT quiz_res_id
       , points
    FROM quiz_res
   WHERE user_id = 1
     AND quiz_id = 1
   ORDER BY timestamp DESC
   LIMIT 1
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE q.points  latest.points) AS count_more
  FROM quiz_res AS q
       CROSS JOIN latest
 WHERE q.quiz_id = 1
   AND q.quiz_res_id != latest.quiz_res_id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
(
    SELECT DISTINCT count(qr_less.user_id) from quiz_result as qr_less
    LEFT JOIN quiz_result qr_max on qr_less.user_id = qr_max.user_id AND qr_less.quiz_result < qr_max.quiz_result
    WHERE qr_max.user_id IS NULL
      AND qr_less.quiz_result < qr.quiz_result
      AND qr_less.quiz_id = qr.quiz_id
      AND qr_less.user_id <> qr.user_id
    GROUP BY qr_less.user_id
)   AS less_count,
(
    SELECT DISTINCT count(qr_equals.user_id) from quiz_result as qr_equals
    LEFT JOIN quiz_result qr_max on qr_equals.user_id = qr_max.user_id AND qr_equals.quiz_result < qr_max.quiz_result
    WHERE qr_max.user_id IS NULL
      AND qr_equals.quiz_result = qr.quiz_result
      AND qr_equals.quiz_id = qr.quiz_id
      AND qr_equals.user_id <> qr.user_id
    GROUP BY  qr_equals.user_id
) AS equals_count,
(
    SELECT DISTINCT count(qr_more.user_id) from quiz_result as qr_more
    LEFT JOIN quiz_result qr_max on qr_more.user_id = qr_max.user_id AND qr_more.quiz_result < qr_max.quiz_result
    WHERE qr_max.user_id IS NULL
      AND qr_more.quiz_result > qr.quiz_result
      AND qr_more.quiz_id = qr.quiz_id
      AND qr_more.user_id <> qr.user_id
    GROUP BY qr_more.user_id
) AS more_count
FROM quiz_result qr
LEFT JOIN quiz_result qr2 ON qr.user_id = qr2.user_id  AND (qr.timestamp < qr2.timestamp)
        WHERE qr2.user_id IS NULL AND qr.quiz_id = 1 AND qr.user_id = 1
        GROUP BY qr.user_id, qr.quiz_result_id, qr2.quiz_result_id;
```

Решение